# %Time% Works When User Initiated But Not When Task Is Triggered

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I have a batch file that's being run with Task Scheduler.  This snippet is failing:

```
Set mm=%DATE:~4,2%
Set dd=%DATE:~7,2%
Set yyyy=%DATE:~10,4%
set t=%TIME:~0,2%

mkdir L:\Weekly\%yyyy%%mm%%dd%%t%\Edge
```

When I initiate the task, this directory is created:

```
L:\Weekly\2016063013\Edge
```

However when the task is run via the scheduled trigger, this directory is created:

```
L:\Weekly\20160702
```

I'm having a hard time debugging this error.  I need the hour to differentiate between backups that were manually triggered after an event vs. the normal nightly/weekly automated routines.

Comment: you mean `L:\Weekly\20160702\Edge` right? When did the task run ? July the 2nd?

Comment: If triggered before 10:00 a.m. then there could be a leading space in %time%. Enclose path in mkdir in a pair of double quotes and/or add set "t=%t: =0%"

Comment: Using `date` and `time` is also locale dependent. For a locale independent solution use `wmic` instead. See my answer [Print datetime in Windows cmd](http://superuser.com/a/1045459)

Comment: @JosefZ you must be right and post an answer. It creates (or tries to create) 2 directories, which also explains the missing `Edge` stuff. Damn spaces.

Comment: I'm trying @JosefZ 's solution tonight.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre , that is literally what it created.

Comment: @JosefZ that was it.  It worked perfectly for the first time since I added the time to the folder name.  Post it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JosefZ solved this for me in a comment to my question.

The script failed to run before noon because when I pulled the hour with **%TIME:~0,2%**, that value was padded with a space, i.e. **" 2"**.  That is why **makedir** did not include the **"\Edge"** subdirectory.

Here is the corrected snippet:

```
Set mm=%DATE:~4,2%
Set dd=%DATE:~7,2%
Set yyyy=%DATE:~10,4%
Set t=%TIME:~0,2%

::replace space with a zero
Set t=%t: =0%

mkdir L:\Weekly\%yyyy%%mm%%dd%%t%\Edge
```